# Android : The application Bluetooth Share has stopped working

Tags: android, bluetooth, motorola-droid

I am facing a weird problem regarding bluetooth on android devices. I have one Motorola Milestone and two HTC-Nexus devices for my android project. I was playing for file transfer using Bluetooth between devices and they were working very fine.

So during the project debugging on Milestone, upon receiving a file, I found some error in my code (fetching from DB) and I stopped debugger in the middle. I got the above titled error. I restarted, reset my device but no vain.

Then same thing happened on my one HTC Nexus device. Any idea/help would be highly appreciated. I have only one week to finish my project.

Exact error is:

The application Bluetooth Share (process com.android.bluetooth) has stopped unexpectedly.
'Force close' /Report options are available only.

Comment: Can you please post the LogCat error messages and relevant parts of the code?

Comment: It's not problem with the code now, its device. I have tested that code for tens of times and it was working correctly. One more thing may be important: My package name is com.android and it has one 'BluetoothShare.java' file also. When I stopped debugger, compiler may have confused it with the original one..I am just making random guess

Comment: using com.android as your namespace may introduce problems, again a logcat would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my devices working by making factory data reset. But to avoid future confusions, I changed my project package name. I think, android OS was causing problems with this namespace as dljava pointed it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did below and it worked straight away.

> Settings > Applications > All > LogsProvider > Clear Data

Give it a go.

Comment: Hi Vadim, sounds great except this app/service/whatever is not listed in my Nexus 5 under Settings > Apps > All.